# How to access web in android browser in android emulator

Tags: android

I have set a proxy in android emulator. I am still not able to access Google in the android browser in android emulator. Can anybody tell me how to access Google in the android emulator?

I have set up the proxy like this

> setting ->wireless and network
>   setting->mobilenetworks->accesspointnames->tekila

Comment: hi mohan i dont know much about the proxy setup but usually if have net connection in the system in which emulator runs then you will be able to connect to internet...

Answer (score 0):

You should add `-http-proxy <proxy>` as parameters when you launch the emulator.

If you are using Eclipse you can setup this by doing a right clic on your project Run > Run Configuration > Target > Additional Emulator Command Line Option.

If you launch the emulator by command line you can add the parameters as follow:

```
emulator -avd <avd_name> -http-proxy <proxy>
```

Cheers

Comment: I gave this  emulator -avd <avd_name> -http-proxy <proxy>  still i am not getting Internet.I am getting web page not available

Comment: Did you remove the proxy in the settings?

Comment: You should try to put -http-proxy <proxy> but remove the proxy settings.